# Zabbix ring topology trigger dependencies

Tags: zabbix

I have a question according redundant network topologies.
I want to track ICMP availability of each Switch in my network. For every Switch I'm using a template that has item `icmpping` and trigger that tracks last value of this item (`ICMP trigger`, actually this is `Template ICMP Ping`). Used Zabbix version is 4.2.8.

Let's say I have linear topology where each device connected to another in straight line: *Switch C <-> Switch B <-> Switch A <-> Aggregation*.
In [such linear topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L8fF.png) trigger dependencies are pretty much obvious: Switch C's availability depends on state of Switch B, Switch B's availability depends on Switch A state, and Switch A depends on availability of Aggregation device. It's not a problem to make trigger dependencies for this.

But now I have a [ring topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/522Pv.png): *Switch C* is connected to both *Switch A* and *Switch B*, *Switch A* and *Switch B* are connected to *Aggregation* device thus making a ring *C <-> A <-> Aggr <-> B <-> C*.
In this case I could [add two dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z43MZ.png) for both Switch A and B availability triggers in Switch C `ICMP trigger` configuration. But if one of uplink switches (A or B) fail I still would not know if C is down or up: [Switch C trigger would be suppressed since at least one parent trigger is fired](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/manual/config/triggers/dependencies):

> Before changing the status of the 'Host is down' trigger, Zabbix will
>   check for corresponding trigger dependencies. If found, and one of
>   those triggers is in 'Problem' state, then the trigger status will not
>   be changed and thus actions will not be executed and notifications
>   will not be sent.

I can imagine several options to do so.

**Option 1:** As a workaround I can manually change `ICMP trigger` to track both this device (Switch C) and two uplinks' `icmpping` item value in a single trigger like this:

> {Switch_C:icmpping[{HOST.IP}].last()}=0
>   and ({Switch_A:icmpping[{HOST.IP}].last()}<>0
>   or {Switch_B:icmpping[{HOST.IP}].last()}<>0)

But since I'm using same templates for all the devices (those which are part of linear topology and those which are in a ring topology), doing so would require to add non-template trigger to every 'ring' device which is quite a lot of work.

**Option 2:** I can monitor interfaces status on A and B that are connected to C, but that is actually even more work than the previous option because I need to add `interface state` item to every switch.

Is there a better way to perform correct monitoring for devices in such ring topologies?

Comment: You can create a single host with two interfaces: Switch A and Switch B. You can then have 3 triggers: "A is down", "B is down", and "both A and B are down". Switch C can then have a dependency just on the last trigger. If switch A and B are in a cluster, you can ask the cluster (via external script or user parameter) about its status.

Comment: @IronBishop no, switches are not in cluster.
So if I want to monitor status of all 3 switches I would need to create 3 additional 'support' hosts. But I have more than 3 switches, and using this option requires to create _n-1_ additional hosts (excl. _Aggregation_). This doesn't scale good enough and is quite similar to **option 1** I've mentioned in question.

Comment: To scale, you need to use a Low Level Discovery. Programmatically generating all the items/hosts/etc you need. https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery The Network Discovery is another option https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/discovery/network_discovery

Comment: I know how to use LLD (for example, I'm using SNMP LLD to discover BGP peers) but I can't imagine how LLD would work here to make dependencies/triggers which are actually based on ICMP, not on SNMP OIDs. I don't need to discover and create IP devices as you mentioned by 2nd link either, also this link says: `It (network discovery) does NOT provide discovery of network topology`. I simply want to make dependencies for ICMP triggers for already added hosts in a known topology to not spawn plenty of triggers. As I explained in a question body, linear topology is not an issue but ring topology is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't", but I'll try to expand it.

First thing to consider, you are checking for the reachability of your switch ip addresses (probably assigned to specific VLAN interfaces) **from the zabbix server point of view**. Is it connected to switch A, B or C ?

Then, modern spanning tree algs treats VLANs with multiple instances, so the vlan dedicated to your switches ip can have a blocked port between B and C while your production vlan could be blocking from A to B. You have multiple logical topologies within a single physical topology.

There is no network topology auto-mapper, it has been requested from time to time but nobody created it: you have to implement it on your own.

You can for instance query the switches with a custom script to:

- get the LLDP or CDP neighbour status from the switches to build the current topology
- dynamically create screens and maps with api calls
- dynamically set up and delete dependancies api calls
- react to changes to the toopology

A simpler way could be:

- set up icmp check to your switch ip addresses with alert
- set up  snmp check for spanning tree recalculation with alert (see `Template SNMP Switch:stpLastTimeChange`)
- install [Netdisco](http://netdisco.org/) to draw the topology

Comment: Thanks for pointing out on Zabbix Server position, I've edited question body so now it's clear. Didn't understand what you meant by _set up icmp check to your switch ip addresses with alert_. If it was about tracking if host is available or not (`Template ICMP ping`) then it's already done, host availability is being monitored. I just want to not fire extra trigger if both uplinks are down. Guess I'll have to either get used to ton of alerts for ring topology hosts because I'd like to stick with single monitoring system or do something similar to **option 1** I've mentioned in question body.

Comment: Or you can implement a topology detector/mapper and public it on Zabbix Share